# Referencing AVCaptureSession won't build project in simulator

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I reference AVCaptureSession an consequently the project will only build for the device. However, I still want to test the rest my app on the simulator as I develop. Do I have to comment out all AVCaptureSession references or is there another way to build for the simulator successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build it using a device with a camera which means you need either a 3GS or an iPhone 4 or you have to create conditionals to check for the existence of the framework/classes. Or you can comment everything out as you've supposed.